# Enable scrollbar for a fixed positionated container

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar, fixed

I have a fixed positionated sidebar which contains some links:

```
<nav id="fixedNav">
    <div class="anchors">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test 9</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="button"></div>
</nav>

#fixedNav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 70%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#fixedNav div {
    float: left;
}
#fixedNav .anchors {
    padding: 1em 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#fixedNav .button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/850bfnb1/

Now I want to add a scrollbar, because not all links are visible, because of the position of this sidebar, but it doesn't work. The scrollbar appears but have no effect :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add

```
height: 100%;
```

to **#fixedNav .anchors** - Now Anchors is filling its parent out.

```
bottom: 0;
```

to  **#fixedNav** -  Now your sure that your fixedNav is on the bottom of the screen. Then add

```
#fixedNav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 70%;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#fixedNav .anchors {
    padding: 1em 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/850bfnb1/5/